# Exposing JSON webservice from Android

Tags: android, json, angularjs, web-services

I am looking to write an app with the following:

1. Expose a http web server using embedded jetty
2. The webservice will allow another device/pc to connect to the android device
3. I would like to expose a JSON RESTfull API from the Android Device
4. The JSON api will be used with Angular  (served from the embeddd Jetty server) to render a webpage on the client browser.

There are many examples on how to consume JSON webservices in Android but I have not been able to find how to *produce* a JSON webservice from Android.

Any suggestions or examples will be greatly appreciated

Regards,

Comment: How are you planning to connect to the web service?  Will the user of the host device tell the client users the IP address to type in?

Comment: Yes that is correct the android device will expose its ip address for the client to connect via browser - this will typically be with both devices no the same local network.

Answer (score -1):

you can use xamp server,it gives inbuilt mysql database,apache connections in fast.And you can able to connect your android project to xamp server by using easy php scripts,and can use easy json methods to retrieve the multiple datas from xamp server quickly.

Comment: xamp is not something I can run on an android device to expose a rest api?